# How to return the component from external function using react-native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

> Here i am using two components,

```
var first = React.createClass(){
     render:function(){
          <View>
             <Text>First Component</Text>
             <TextInput style={{borderWidth:1,borderColor:'red'}} onPress={getData()}/>
          </View>
      }
})
    function getData(){
      <second/>
    }
    var second = React.createClass(){
         render:function(){
              <View>
                 <ScrollView>
                   <Text>Second component</Text>
                 </ScrollView>
              </View>
          }
    })
```

> Required Result: First Component Second component

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you're trying to show a new component when something is clicked? The way I would handle this is by using state. Generally you only want JSX to show up in your `render` method.

So what you should do is have something like:

```
var first = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      showSecond: false
    };
  },
  _handlePress: function() {
    return this.setState(showSecond(true));
  },
  render: function() {
    <View>
      <View style={styles.first}>
        <Text> ... </Text>
        <TextInput />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={@_handlePress}>
          <Text> Button </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      {if showSecond
        <View style={styles.second}>
          <ScrollView>
            <Text> Scroll Item </Text>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      }
    </View>
  }
});
```

Now what happens is when you press the button you change state, which rerenders your component, and now that the state is true, it shows the `second` component

Comment: No i want to call the second component from external function only, that's the scenario i need

Comment: so i'm not sure why you would HAVE to use an external function, but even so, you would have to do a similar thing as above. You have to specify where in your rendered DOM the new component has to show up by using the `if` statement and watching for state. Then instead of having the component already there like above, you could call a function that returns the component. So on press, change state. The new state triggers the `if` statement and in turn the external function that returns JSX. It seems highly unnecessary to do it that way though.

Comment: The second component I am talking about is required to be called in several other components. To enable code reuse and ease of maintenance I wanted to write a set of components that will be called within other components.

This is how we are doing it in react. Will try in react-native and revert. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So if you have a component that shows up a lot, like a spinner. I would just write it in its own file with `module.exports = React.createClass({..})` and then in every component that needs it, just `require('./ui/spinner')` to add the spinner to wherever you need it. That's how I do it for React and React-Native